# Aggregating T-statistics and F-statistics across monthly cross-sectional regressions

Tags: regression, t-test, panel-data, robust-standard-error, f-statistic

I am trying to replicate the results in Table V of the paper *[Individualism and Momentum around the World (2010) by Chui et al](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1540-6261.2009.01532.x)*. This is attached herewith.

### Dataset:

- ***Dependent variable***: Monthly returns on momentum portfolios across 48 countries. The dataframe is shown below:

[image]

- ***Independent variables***: Monthly indicators of trading behaviour across 48 countries (egs. market trading volume, stock market volatility etc.), market development (egs. private credit-to-GDP ratio, an index on control over capital flows etc.) and institutional quality.

### Desired results:

The below table summarises the results I am trying to reproduce:
[image]

According to the paper:

- This table reports the time-series averages of cross-sectional OLS estimates of the coefficients. The t-statistics are in parentheses.
- The Newey–West (1994) heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation consistent estimates of standard errors are used to compute these t-statistics.
- F1 (an F-statistic) is used to test the hypothesis that
  all the estimated slope coefficients except the coefficient on Indv are jointly equal to zero. F2 (an
  F-statistic) is used to test the hypothesis that all the estimated slope coefficients are jointly equal
  to zero. The p-values are in parentheses.

### The problem:

I have already run cross-sectional regressions of the dependent variable on the independent variables for every month, and have monthly estimates of regression coefficients, NW-adjusted t-statistics and the F-statistic

Based on this, I have also calculated the average regression coefficient for each independent variable across all months.

***However, I am not sure about the most statistically sound approach to get:***

- ***a t-statistic aggregated across all the monthly cross-sectional regressions for each independent variable***
- ***a single F-statistic aggregated across cross-sectional regressions***

***How can one go about calculating the above statistics?***

### My view/ thinking:

Taking the average of t-stats for a given variable or F-stats across all regressions doesn't feel right to me.

I know that the t-stat (NW-adjusted) is calculated by dividing the regression coefficient by the NW-adjusted standard error. So, perhaps one could divide the regression coefficient averaged across all monthly regressions by the standard error across all these monthly regressions.

However, the above approach would not take into account the Newey-West adjustment made to the standard error's of each month's regression to adjust for heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation.

Any help in answering the above question would be appreciated. Thanks